Control of relative position of 'pic's and text in 'matrix'
I want to create a matrix of 'pic's with annotations with precise aligment. In my project code for the pics is stored in external files, is pulled in with \input and cannot be easily modified (it's a rather complex 3d structure). Here is the minimalist code for my case.
I would like text to be aligned by the middle of the column, and all text in the row to have same baseline. I would like all 'pic's to be in the middle of their column and at the bottom of their row.
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}

\tikzset{ OO/.pic = { 
  \path (0,0) node[circle] {O1} -- (0,1) node[circle] {O2} ;
}}

\tikzset{ QQ/.pic = {
  \path (0,0)  node {Q1} -- (1,0) node {Q2} ;
}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]

\matrix[align=center]
{
 \pic  {OO};       & \pic{QQ};       & \pic{OO};       \\
 \node {circles};  & \node {square}; & \node {cicles}; \\
 \pic  {OO};       & \pic{QQ};       & \pic{OO};       \\
 \node {circles};  & \node {square}; & \node {cicles}; \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This is confusing code. And you don't use the TikZ library matrix either. It is also not clear why the matrix environment in TikZ is used here. I wouldn't recommend this library either, but rather something like tcolorbox; especially since it seems to be about external graphics that should be inserted with \input.

@cis I think they aren't external graphics but tikz pics and the code is being input, rather than an image? At least, that's how I understood it.

pics are not full-fledged nodes and do not have the same positioning possibilities. (But see tikzext for some ways to get them to behave in more node-like ways.)
Probably the simplest way to get the alignment you want, at least in simple cases, is just to adjust the pics so (0,0) is at the centre of the baseline i.e. at the centre of the pic.
\documentclass[tikz, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ OO/.pic = { 
  \path (0,-.5) node[circle] {O1} -- (0,.5) node[circle] {O2} ;
}}

\tikzset{ QQ/.pic = {
  \path (-.50,0)  node {Q1} -- (.5,0) node {Q2} ;
}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

  \matrix (m)[matrix of nodes,align=center,every node/.append style={anchor=base,align=center}]
{
 \pic  {OO};       & \pic{QQ};       & \pic{OO};       \\
 circles  & square & cicles \\
 \pic  {OO};       & \pic{QQ};       & \pic{OO};       \\
 circles  & square & cicles \\
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Alternatively, you could investigate tikzext or save each pic in a box and then position the box. (A coffin would offer even more control.)
Another option would be to make each a separate tikzpicture and replace the current tikzpicture matrix with a tabular, for example.

Is it possible to adjust position of 0.0 in the pic via a coordinate transformation and not changing the pic body? Ideally with shift extracted from bonding point.

@permeakra You can pass options through to the pic code, but the code has to use them and you can't (that I know of) use a point within the pic to anchor it. For that, you'd need a node. If you place all your pics first, you could put them in localised scopes with names and use those, but you'd have to build everything else around pre-placed pics. If you really need to align the pic to the environment, rather than the other way around, save them into boxes in their own tikzpictures and then use the boxes with the usual alignment methods.

That the latter probably is that I would have to do. Thanks
